# how do you create a scroll bar menu that scrolls only on the content and not on the header

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have a list of names : first and last. The list is long, so I need to have a scroll bar menu. When I scroll, I should only scroll on the names and not on the column header. 
I managed to do so but the problem is that the second column elements are not displayed right under the column name as you can see here  http://jsfiddle.net/MmLQL/44/.

```
   <table border=1 width=200px >
    <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>looong column name </th>
    </tr>

    </table>
    <div  class="div_scroll">
        <table border=1 width=200px  >
               <tr>
                   <td>John</td>
                   <td>Smith</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Doe</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
```

And even if I put the header and the content in the same table, and create a div to wrap the table content and add a class to that div to enable scrolling, it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/MmLQL/43/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a fix for the code you have provided - but this solution worked for me before. [CSS Play Scrolling Tables](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/tablescroll.html)

Comment: your second attempt is just flat out in correct.  it isn't valid to have a div inside a `<tr>` and outside a `<td>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need javascript for this. Just set the widths of the columns to be equal. Here's a quick example:

`th, td {
    width: 50%;
}`

[**View it on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MmLQL/49/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of the columns to be the same for each table.  Maybe create a css class for each column and apply them to the columns in the tables.

Example CSS classes:

```
.ColumnOne { width: 40%; }
.ColumnTwo { width: 60%; }
```

Then apply to the columns:

```
<table border=1 width=200px >
  <tr>
    <th class="ColumnOne">First Name</th>
    <th class="ColumnTwo">looong column name </th>
  </tr>
</table>
<div  class="div_scroll">
  <table border=1 width=200px  >
   <tr>
     <td class="ColumnOne">John</td>
     <td class="ColumnTwo">Smith</td>
   </tr>
...
```